# Creating a mysql database with regID's

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing Push notifications for my app at the moment. As you know, every user has to register via a certain regID which is stored on the server. I hav been following [this](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-gcm-service/) tutorial. ( I have used mainly it's code for the server setup aswell)

The problem is, in this tutorial, the regID is stored in a simple txt file and can be only sent to one user (whose id is stored at that time). Now I want to save ALL registered ID's and when pressing the button (as seen in the tutorial).

I want to send the notification to ALL users AT ONCE. Is that possible? If yes how? (I already started some researching, I have to create a mySQL database and the php file needs somehow to access that database, right?)

EDIT:

```
class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        include_once './db_connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($gcm_regid) {
        // insert user into database
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gcm_users(gcm_regid) VALUES('$gcm_regid', NOW())");
        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details
            $id = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gcm_users WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
            // return user details
            if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                return mysql_fetch_array($result);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Getting all users
     */
    public function getAllUsers() {
        $result = mysql_query("select * FROM gcm_users");
        return $result;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to insert users' `regID` in your `mysql` database. For notifying all users, `select` all the users using a query and send the notifications to all of them.

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) tutorial can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial, could you help me please a bit out on how to "select" all users?

Comment: if its a mysql database then use a query `select * from gcm_users`. Then iterate over this result and send notification to each one.

Comment: See the `db_functions.php` file in the above tutorial.

Comment: Thank you. Also, if I only want to have the regId stored in the database, I have to remove "name", "email" and "creation_date", right?

Answer (score 1):

You can read data from file and store in collection and from collection you can retrieve regID and pass this to your push notification method.